# View Binding is working for one layout, but not working for another

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

New to android development, I'm trying to apply View Binding as they are the recommended view referencing method by Google as of now. I have two layouts content_main.xml and content_note_list.xml. I got the first 'content_main_xml' (MainActivity) to work with View Binding. However I'm having trouble implementing view binding for second 'content_note_list.xml'.

Below is the code that keeps crashing the app within the simulator
[here's the image of the code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAI2d.png)

It works when I don't use the view binding ie.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_list)
```

but as soon as I try to use the view bindings, it opens up the app and crashes momentarily

```
setContentView(binding.root)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I have followed the description provided by the official android dev site, multiple videos.
Any help would be necessary.

EDIT:
[content_note_list.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V7u6.png) [activity_note_list.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Frcw.png)

Apologize for attaching image files, the code becomes all messed up when I try to append it.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your code [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the name. Remembering from [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding). If your layout is `result_profile.xml`

```
<LinearLayout ... >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name" />
    <ImageView android:cropToPadding="true" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ViewBinding will generate `ResultProfileBinding`.

> If view binding is enabled for a module, a binding class is generated for each XML layout file that the module contains. Each binding class contains references to the root view and all views that have an ID. The name of the binding class is generated by converting the name of the XML file to Pascal case and adding the word "Binding" to the end.

So, with that in mind. if your layout is `activity_note_list` it will generate ActivityNoteListBinding class or something like that. In your code, you are setting `ContentNoteListBinding` class.  Try to replace `ContentNoteListBinding` with `ActivityNoteListBinding`. Also, if it does not solve the problem. Try to add the code from console log. it has more details about the error.

**Update**

If you want to handle View or ViewGroup which are include in your activity/fragment over `<include>` tag, you can access these views almost directly. You need to add an Id in this tag `<include>`. And then you will have access to these components: For example:

This is a activity_note_list.xml

```
........
<include 
    id="+@id/ly_content_list_note"
    layout="@layout/content_list_note"/>
........
```

And content_note_list.xml

```
<listView
    id="+id/listNotes"
    .......
/>
```

Now in your Activity class, you can access in this way:

```
binding.lyContentListNote.listNotes
```

As you can see, first access directly to the id of the container, which is `ly_content_list_note` and then all the view components inside that, in this case `listNotes`.

Comment: So, I found out that the activity is split into two separate parts, content_name.xml and activity_name.xml where they have different views (buttons, listviews, etc) you can add to each. In the activity_note_list.xml file, the content_note_list file is included, I need to access references from both layouts (activity and content) by view binding. How would that work?

Comment: Both xml files have separate binding objects generated. ActivityNoteListBinding and ContentNoteListBinding. Most of the references I need to access are in the ContentNoteListBinding. However, I still need to access the references in the other layout as well.

Comment: Could you please add the xml of your content, acitivity and another xml that you are using. I think you can access directly but I need to understand how you xml of you activity is structured

Answer (score 1):

adding to @rguzman answer, to avoid running into issues like this where the type of the binding is accidentally set wrong, you can use `DataBindingUtil` library.

For **Activity**

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.your_file)
```

For **Fragments**

```
 binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.your_file, container, false)

//other logic

return binding.root
```

[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil) to official docs for more info